# Hw to append the content of a column to the beginning of a list in the same row in R

Tags: r, string, list, append

For example, a dataframe lib has columns lib$a and lib$b, and b contains a list.

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| couch | c(apple, pear, orange) |
| table | c(lemon, lime, banana) |

The desired output is:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| couch | c(couch, apple, pear, orange) |
| table | c(table, lemon, lime, banana) |

I need to do this for every row in the dataframe. Thanks!

Comment: Would you pls `dput(your_data)` ?

Comment: Could you please share code to create the data frame? Either `dput(your_sample_data)` which will be copy/pasteable, or code to create it directly? And if your real data is more than 1 row, a 2-row example would probably be good to make sure it generalizes.

Comment: Hello. Is how it looks now alright?

Comment: Thanks for adding a second row, but your sample data is still in a format that's very difficult to import into R and test solutions on. If you have that as an R object in your environment, you can simply use `dput(your_sample_data)` to make a copy/pasteable version including all class and structure information. Or share valid R code, e.g. `df = data.frame(cat = c("couch", "table"), dog = ...)`. Doing so removes all ambiguity about the input and makes it very easy for people to try to help you. We want to copy/paste something from the question into R and have it work to make the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowwise()` and `mutate()`, like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(dog = list(c(dog,cat)))
```

Output:

```
  cat   dog      
  <chr> <list>   
1 couch <chr [4]>
2 table <chr [4]>
```

Input:

```
structure(list(cat = c("couch", "table"), dog = list(c("apple", 
"pear", "orange"), c("lemon", "lime", "banana"))), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```